# image not showing in JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I made an application that uses an image as the background to an image, when i run it in eclipse it works perfectly, but when i pack it into a .Jar file the image is not showing.
i surfed Stackoverflow for Answers i found similar posts and i tried the solutions but nothing worked.

here is what i ended up doing.

```
private void init(){
setPreferredSize( new Dimension( w, h ) );
setVisible(true);

URL url = getClass().getResource("Graph2.png");
System.out.println("Value = " + url);
img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
}
```

the constructor calls this function to initialize the GUI
then i call this function in the paintcomponent to draw the image

```
private void initializeGrid(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

}
```

not sure what is the problem i tried putting the image everywhere, from a folder outside the src to inside the bin to inside the GUI package in the bin nothing worked.

thanks in advance

Comment: What does the `System.out.println()` method print out?

Comment: Value = file:/C:/Users/ahmed/CollegeProjects/Numerical/bin/Graphics/Graph2.png

Comment: What about when you run it from the .jar?

Comment: i added it's value to a JLabel it's null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to set this up is to create your folders like this in Eclipse:

```
bin/
resources/
src/
```

Create your package structure in `resources` exactly like it is in `src` and `bin`.  Copy your image file to the same package in `resources` as the class that will try to load it in `src`.

In Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source, add both `src` and `resources` as source folders.  Now when you build the project the contents of `resources` will be copied over to `bin` and it will work from your IDE as well as from a JAR.

Comment: i have this structure
bin 
  graphics  
  math

  
src  
  graphics  
  math  
resources  
  graphics  

i added the pic at resources/graphics and still nothing happened

Comment: i can't add new line for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify absolute location to you image in JAR, like

`URL url = getClass().getResource("/com/test/mypackage/Graph2.png");`

if your image place near of your class or

`URL url = getClass().getResource("/Graph2.png");`

if your image place in root of JAR file

Also please note about case of file name "Graph2.png" is not "graph2.png"